# Problems with registration (IdentityUser)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I use Identity and can't access the confirmation page (There is no transition to another page from the Register page). Using migrations, I created tables for users, but by clicking the "Register" button, this page is refreshed.

IdentityHostingStartup:

```
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AspNetRunConnection")
            ));
        });
    }
```

Register.cshtml:

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/adminlte.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition register-page">
    <div class="register-box">
        <div class="register-logo">
            <a href="~/Home"><b>Admin</b>LTE</a>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
                    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                </form>
                <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
                    <p>- OR -</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook mr-2"></i>
                        Sign up using Facebook
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">
                        <i class="fab fa-google-plus mr-2"></i>
                        Sign up using Google+
                    </a>
                </div>
                <a href="login.html" class="text-center">I already have a membership</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("Category");

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubCategory>().ToTable("SubCategory");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Product");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("Company");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().ToTable("Country");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Review>().ToTable("Review");
    }
```

ConfigureServices:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AspNetRunConnection")
        ));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning));
        });

        services.AddMvc(o =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });


    }
```

Register:

> [image]

Structure:

> [image]

```
!UPD
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace E_Store2021.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your ```Register.cshtml``` u didnt have  ```asp-action="Register"``` that action. u have a ```asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl"``` that is why its keep refreshing itself

Comment: Can you show us the post method?

Comment: @BerkGarip it's Razor Page model. I updated topic

Comment: Debug to check `var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);` what's the value of the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your register failed (maybe the user already exists), so it return back to the current page instead of going to confirm, while you didn't show the error message in the view, so you don't know if the account is successfully registerd.

Add this line to your custom Register view to show the error message:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
```

Comment: `<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>` it helped me a lot.